# How can I reuse an angularJS UI View in other ui-view

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

So I want to have two big pages. I cannot use `ui-view` because many `widgets/ sections` of the views are shared (they remain on the screen without loading). The moment a user clicks on a button, the app should move to a different state with merely other sections changing with some animations.
Now, what I tried till now is nested views. But these are only one directional top down architecture. I could not find a way to share views.
I am not using mere `ng-include` or a directive because I want it to follow a state by state approach keeping intact the history with a URL mapped to it's own template.
The chances are many views are going to reuse/ share the inner views like widgets.

**Config**

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard',{
    url : "/dashboard",
    views : {
        'dashboard' : {
            templateUrl: './templates/dashboard.html'
        }
    }
}).state('dashboard.personalDetails', {
    url : '/personalDetails',
    views : {
        'main' : {
            templateUrl: "./templates/personalDetails.html"
        }
    }
}).state('shipment',{
    url : '/personalDetails',
    views : {
        localView1 : {}
        localView2 : //reuse the personal details view
    }
})
```

This is just one example, I basically want to reuse my views as widgets across many pages. Is it possible with ui-router? If yes, then how?

**PS: Don't go on this specific example. The actual implementation is for a trading detail page in banking application. And due to policies I cannot share that code structure.**

Comment: what do you mean by `reuse ui-view`?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are asking however you can always create objects to represent similar views and pass those objects to a state definition

```
var subviews_1={
    'widget_1' {templateUrl: '..'},
    'widget_2' {templateUrl: '..'},
}

$stateProvider.state('shipment',{
    url : '/personalDetails',
    views : subviews_1
})
```